# Accessing parent value inside Eloquent Relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my controller,

```
User::find(1)->with('matches')->get()
```

And in the Model,

```
public function matches()
{
    $userAge = $this->age; // Trying to access something like this

    return $this->hasMany('App\Others', 'location', 'location')
                ->selectRaw('*, ('.$userAge.' = age) as match');
}
```

How can I access the User's age like `$this->age`? Or Is that even possible? I already tried to `var_dump($this)` to see what I can get, but no luck.

My original goal was to inner join the `User` and `Others` table/model.
I have a query like this:

```
SELECT (a.age = b.age) as match
FROM user a 
LEFT JOIN others b ON a.location= b.location 
WHERE a.location = 'Somewhere'
```

I know I can do it easily with Query builder, but I think it is better if I can do it using Eloquent/Relationships.

Hope you guys get my point.

I'm still new in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use accessors and mutators on Eloquent models for this.

```
public function getAgeAttribute () {
    // add custom query logic here
    ...
    return $queryResult->age;
}
```

Then your User model can access it's `age` attribute as an instance:

```
$user->age
```

or within the Model itself:

```
$this->age
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Anytime you name a function on a Model starting with `get` and ending with `Attribute`, you create a mutator which allows to define custom attributes or modify what is returned from existing attributes.

Comment: This does not work when I use it in a "relation" method like `matches` where I use `with('matches')`. This works only on methods like `User::find(1)->findMyAge()`

Comment: Accessors absolutely do work in "relation" methods, it's equivalent to accessing a regular model attribute. What problem are you having using it? A specific exception arise?

Comment: I tried to to do `var_dump($this->age)` inside `matches` and it is `NULL`. And in the accessor code you gave, I get `ErrorException 
Undefined variable: queryResult` as expected.

Comment: `$queryResult` is a made up variable there for demonstration purposes. You need to place your real code within that function and return the age value.

Comment: Yes I figured that. But if that is really what you mean, then there is nothing new. I still need to manually find that specific `User` again. Which just makes my code longer but with same result. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: I apparently am not understanding your intention clearly. If `matches` if a function on your `User` model, `age` is an attribute on `User` also? Or `Others`? If `age` is a `User` attribute then there should be no reason `$this->age` doesn't work within the `User` model, unless `age` is the `$hidden` array.

Comment: I thought I can access it too. But I think I understand now the problem and my approach and plan will not work. The reason `matches` has `null` age  is because the query is not executed yet. Just a blueprint. It is `with('matches')` only. But I don't know if that is true? Because I should atleast get the `id`

Answer (score 1):

You get it wrong. The relationship should look like:

```
public function matches()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Others', 'location', 'location');
}
```

Then get the user with related matches with:

```
$user = User::with('matches')->find(1);
```

And then you'll have access to user's age and matches:

```
User is {{ $user->age }} years old
@foreach ($user->matches as $match)
    {{ $match->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: No, there is more reason why I put it in select fields, I don't need to just print them. I really need to access the `age` inside matches, because I need it to include in my query as you see this `('.$userAge.' = age) as match`.. because I will use that later to order and limit the results, like `ORDER BY match DESC LIMIT 10`